# Encoding Issue in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, encoding, character-encoding

I am getting data from a Stored Procedure and creating a text file, below is my code for converting a datatable to a text file by calling this method.

```
StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.Default);

if (writeWithColumns)
{
    string Columns = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataColumn column in datatable.Columns)
    {
        Columns += column.ColumnName.Trim() + delimiter;
    }

    str.WriteLine(Columns.Remove(Columns.Length - 1, 1));

    foreach (DataRow datarow in datatable.Rows)
    {
        string row = string.Empty;

        foreach (object items in datarow.ItemArray)
        {
            row += items.ToString().Trim() + delimiter;
        }

        str.WriteLine(row.Remove(row.Length - 1, 1));
    }

    str.Flush();
    str.Close();
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when converting some files I am getting correct ANSI format, with an **Û** delimiter:

[image]

but some files are changing the delimiter to **л**:

[image]

I don't understand why some files are having correct encoding while some are having incorrect one.

Comment: What's different between the two cases? Different computer?

Comment: Can you show any occurence of `delimiter = ...`?

Comment: basically i want to export a file with delimiter Û and when i am exporting using above method some files encoding are fine, i have checked it in notepad++ but some files are changing my delimiter to  л .

Comment: Have you tried writing the file using `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Default`. UTF8 is widely supported and understood. `Encoding.Default` is unknown.

Comment: Yes, i have tried UTF8 and it works fine, but i have requirement that i have to give file in ANSI encoding.

Comment: No difference evident from this code snippet. Need the statement for declaration and initiation for delimiter

Comment: ANSI Encoding to what CodePage? `Local` to whom? Are you sure this (Default/Local) CodePage will supports all the original characters? Anyway, you can convert the encoding. But you can't blindly use the Local Encoding and write chars to a file. Apparently, some Local Encodings don't support some of the characters you're trying to use. Maybe, you'll find more in the future. See [Encoding.Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.convert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)